# Multi input independent rxjs stream

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

**The idea**

I have a search bar which will search for text when either:

1. Term longer than 2 characters is entered into search input
2. Search button is pressed

My code right now is:

```
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

const input$ = Observable.fromEvent(input, 'keyup')
  .map(e => e.target.value)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .debounceTime(200)
  .filter(val => val.length > 2);

const button$ = Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click');

Observable.zip(button$, input$, (butt, inp) => false)
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

However this only console logs when I do both. How can I have each of the events fire off console.log independent of each other while the stream is combined? Is it event possible to have them as part of the same stream?

Comment: Do you want `combineLatest`, rather than `zip`? The whole point of zip is that it's pairs. See e.g. http://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you, that made it work, just had to use `.startsWith`  and deal with filtering later on.